# Instantiating a Thread within a foreach loop in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a function that connects to a Multiple SQL server instances to fetch a set of data from each server for comparison of the data among multiple environments

I have a collection of the connection strings
I am calling this method in a foreach loop for each connection string in the collection

Since the data is fetched from different servers individually one at a time it takes up a lot of time
I would like to know if i use threads to call this method every time what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: What do you want to do with the data that you get from different servers?

Comment: Are you just dumping the data somewhere once it's retrieved from each server?

Comment: How do you plan to use the data? Also, see if you can optimize your SQL queries (if possible).

Comment: I intend to use the data to compare the data from multiple servers for a set of input and compare this data to report any differeneces found in different Development Environments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this

1.) create a set of tasks and then do "await Task.WaitAll(listOfTasks)"

2.) Use Parallel.ForEach

3.) Manage threads

**Managing threads**

I do this in 2 steps:

1.) Create a list of threads

```
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
foreach(var connectionString in ConnectionStrings)
{
   var thread = new Thread(DoWork);
   thread.Start(connectionString);
   threads.Add(thread);

}
```

2.) Join the threads to the current thread, has the effect of blocking until all are complete.

```
foreach(var thread in threads)
{
   thread.Join()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could `Join` the threads and make the program wait all of them until they are finished. It is a good pratice before moving to the next step. Look the code bellow with the comment, for sample:

```
// list of threads
List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();

// list of the results for each thread
List<SomeTypeDto> results = new List<SomeTypeDto>();

foreach(var connectionString in connectionStringList) {

    // create the thread
    Thread thread = new Thread(() => {

        // access the database

        SomeTypeDto result = /* process some result data*/;

        lock (results) {
            results.Add(result);
        }
    });

    threads.Add(thread);
}

// start all threads
foreach (Thread thread in threads) {
    thread.Start();
}

// Wait for all the threads to finish 
foreach (Thread thread in threads) {
    thread.Join();
}
```